# Where can I find a thorough DirectShow tutorial?

Tags: directshow

I've read through the MSDN documentation on DirectShow and it's still confusing. I feel like I need more context for what the objects are: Graphs, Pins, Filters...etc. A Google search doesn't give me much to work with. What do I need to grok DirectShow?

EDIT: The wikipedia page on [DirectShow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectShow) does a pretty good job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSDN Magazine has a nice article in their July 2002 Issue: [DirectShow: Core Media Technology in Windows XP Empowers You to Create Custom Audio/Video Processing Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301631.aspx)

Pascal Mignot from Université de Reims has gathered information from MSDN documentation into a [single document](http://mathinfo.univ-reims.fr/image/mmVideo/cours/DirectShow3Annexe.pdf), which gives a nice overview.

Answer (score 1):

Also, there is a very good book on 
[DirectShow](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Microsoft%C2%AE-DirectShow%C2%AE-Television-Pro-Developer/dp/0735618216).

Comment: Thanks, I just bought a used copy on ebay. There are mixed reviews on it, hopefully it will be good.

Answer (score 1):

http://betterlogic.com/roger/?p=3088

has some good links, as also I have some demo projects here: https://github.com/rdp

Answer (score 1):

The SDK has quite a few samples which may help. Fortunately I had some existing code to walk through, but it sure is lengthy and as often with MS, the interfaces don't really look like what they do, but instead focus more on juggling pointers, typecasting and COM trouble, instead of focusing on the intended functionality.